# Flink maintaining configuration state

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use case of maintaining configuration in Flink that I don't really know how to handle.

Let's say that I have some configuration stored somewhere and I need it to do my processing. At the initialization of the Flink job, I want to load all the configuration.

This configuration can also be modified during the run of the Flink job, so I must keep in memory the state of this configuration and update it when needed. The updates of configuration are accessible from a KafkaSource.

So here is what I have :

I have a function that load the whole configuration, keep it in a state and associate it with my data stream :

```
public class MyConfiguration extends RichFlatMapFunction<Row, Row>{
    private transient MapState<String, MyConfObject> configuration;

    @Override
    public void open(MyConfiguration config) throws Exception{
        MapStateDescriptor<String,MyConfObject> descriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<String,MyConfObject>(
                "configuration",
                BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                ...
        );
        configuration = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(descriptor);
        configuration.putAll(...);   // Load configuration from somewhere
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Row value, Collector<Row> out) throws Exception {
        MyConfObject conf = configuration.get(...);
        ...               // Associate conf with data
        out.collect(value);
    }
}
```

And my pipeline look like this :

```
DataStream<Row> dataStream = ...; // My data stream
DataStream<Map<String, MyConfObject> streamConf = 
     env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<Row>(..., ..., ...)) // The stream of configuration updates
        .map(...); 

return dataStream
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...)
    .flatMap(new MyConfiguration())

    ... //Do some processing

    .map(m -> {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m);
        return json.getBytes();
    });
```

What I want is to use the stream of configuration updates `streamConf` to update the State variable inside the `MyConfiguration` flat map function. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you write a source that reads config info from Kafka and then broadcasts changes to the config via broadcast stream to the mapping function.  The mapping function would store the complete, current config in its persisted state and the broadcast stream means that all instances of the mapping function would get all config changes.

Comment: I didn't know about broadcast streams. Seems to be what I am looking for. Thanks !